# PHP stringtotime function first weekday

Tags: php, date

```
echo date("d-M-Y", strtotime("first monday 2019-07"));
```

Shouldn't the output of this line be 01-Jul-2019? Thats the first monday in July but the output is: 08-Jul-2019.

What is the error im making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" first monday 2019-07 " returns the date of the first monday of july excluding the start date (in this case 1st july 2019). Where as "first monday of 2019-07" returns the date of the first monday of july including the start date.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
first monday of 2019-07
```

Instead of `first monday 2019-07`.

Comment: Nice thank you very much, this is what i wanted. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: Isn't it obvious?

Comment: for sure i noticed. My question was what "first monday 2019-07" is doing because its working when the first monday isn't the first day of the month.

Answer (score 2):

Use,

```
echo date("d-M-Y", strtotime("first monday of 2019-07"));
```

You can find [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) php instructions to parsing date as natural languages.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php